# Create a suggestion list using typeahead.js and source from database

Tags: php, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

Sorry for any inconvenience to understand my question

How can I make the suggestion list work using `typeahead.js` and with database as the source?

Before trying the `database` code, the `fixed source` code is working. But when I tried the `database` code, it does not work.

`Fixed source` code:

```
<html>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//raw.github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.q.typeahead').typeahead({                               
                name: "suggestion typeahead",
                local: ["italy", "malaysia", "new york", "USA", "England"]
            });
        });
    </script>

    <input type="text" class="q typeahead" id="citiesInput" onkeyup="typeahead(this.value)" />

</html>
```

`Database` code:

```
<html>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//raw.github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.q.typeahead').typeahead({                               
                name: "suggestion typeahead",
                remote: '/suggestion.php?q=%QUERY'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <input type="text" class="q typeahead" id="citiesInput" onkeyup="typeahead(this.value)" />

</html>
```

suggestion.php:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; //connect with database
$query = $_GET["q"];
if($query != "")
{
$safequery = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query);
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '%" . $safequery . "%' OR keywords LIKE '%" . $safequery . "%' OR link LIKE '%" . $safequery . "%' LIMIT 4";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$number_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($number_of_result > 0) {
    //results found here and display them
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { //show first 10 results
        $title = $row["title"];
        $link = $row["link"];
        echo "<div id='sugg-search-result'>";
        echo "<a href='$link' id='sugg-title'>" . $title . "</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to return Json data not html from the server side.
You could also use the *filter* typeahead option to convert your data to the *Datum* format the typeahead control requires.  See the typeahead documentation for this.